# Summarizing across multiple columns in sql or crystal

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports-2008, summary

I was wondering if there was a way to get a distinct count on a certain column based on the value of a second column while still getting a total count of the first column. This is an example of the issue I'm facing. I have a query that returns an i-Vent type, ID, Status, and linked medication orders for a pharmacy intervention system. The interventions are grouped by i-Vent type. The Status can be one of five values or NULL. I need to be able to count how many i-Vents were recorded as each of the six possible values for Status.

An example set may look similar to this:

```
________________________________________________________
Type    |  ID    |  Status  |  Linked Meds
________________________________________________________

IV2PO   | 1234   | Accepted | pantoprazole IV
IV2PO   | 1234   | Accepted | pantoprazole PO
IV2PO   | 1235   | NULL     | NULL
IV2PO   | 1236   | Pending  | metoclopramide IV
IV2PO   | 1236   | Pending  | metoclopramide PO
IV2PO   | 1236   | Pending  | Pharmacy Consult - IV2PO
Consult | 1237   | Rejected | NULL
________________________________________________________
```

The group summary should list IV2PO having a total count of 3 with a count of 1 for "Accepted", 1 for "NULL", and 1 for "Pending"; and Consult having a total count of 1 with a count of 1 for "Rejected".

Please take notice of the duplicate values caused by having more than one medication/order liked to an i-Vent.

Ultimately I'm building the final report in Crystal Reports so if there is a way to get the correct counts there that would be fine as well. I have a version of this which uses a subreport to get the linked medications/orders, but I'd like to find a better alternative to take less time to run and use fewer resources.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question. Based on the Table and desired results, it sounds like the query you want would never show more than 1 for a result.
    type          |       Rejected       |       Accepted       |     Pending      |         Null
    ________________________________________________________
    IV2PO       |             0             |             1             |           1           |       1
    Consult     |              1             |             0             |           0          |        0


Is this what you want?

Comment: Wow! that formatting did not show up how i thought it would.

Comment: where do you want the count to be displayed?

Comment: There are two groups in this report; Type and ID. I need a summary in the Type group which shows total by Type along with a value for each possible Status. The correct summary for the example given would be: IV2PO 3 total, Accepted 1, Pending 1, NULL 1, Rejected 0; Consult 1 total, Accepted 0, Pending 0, NULL 0, Rejected 1.

Answer (score 0):

In Crystal Reports you can use Count distinct summary option

When creating a "Summary", using the Count function may not be desirable. It is often the case that a report must only return the number of unique contact records, as other tables (i.e. History) may contain multiple rows for each customer.
Select Insert | Summary.
Select the fieldname you wish to summarize.
Make sure to select Distinct Count as the Summary Operation.

Comment: I've tried this method already and only get false answers.I can get a Distinct Count on the number of "Type" values easily enough this way using a distinct count on ID, but it doesn't properly summarize the "Status" values. I tried using a Running Summary with a Distinct Count of ID and a formula which looks for just one value of "Status", but have only been able to get a count of 0 (zero) or 1 using this method.

Comment: I have two groups in this report. The first is by "Type" and the second by "ID" to keep the values of each unique i-Vent together. Remember I need to get a count of each of the possible values for "Status" in the summary of the first group as well as the total number of each "Type" by group. It's the "Status" summary I'm having trouble with. Since the addition of the "Linked Meds" adds duplicate values for Type, ID, and Status, simple counts using variables don't work for the summarizing of the "Status" values.

Comment: I tried using a variable to create the count along with evaluating the previous entry (e.g.: If ID <> Previous(ID) then x:=x+1) but get an error in Crystal stating I can't use a summary value in that equation. Also tried a similar method with the WhilePrintingRecords function with the same error result. In the example I gave the correct Summary in the report would be: IV2PO 3 total, Accepted 1, Pending 1, NULL 1, Rejected 0; Consult 1 total, Accepted 0, Pending 0, NULL 0, Rejected 1. Getting the total by Type is already correct (Distinct Count on ID), but the Status is wrong.